# Spark structured streaming on k8s

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We are running a structured streaming process with spark 2.4.3 that reads data from kafka, transform the data (flattens and creates some columns using udf) after that the data is written back to a kafka to a different topic. the stream is processingTime is every two minutes. after 10-12 hours we noticed that our pods are going down because of high memory consumption. As I explained above we have no aggregation and not using persist on dataset. What we noticed is that the heap memory is constantly growing.
 any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We found the solution to the issue, it took a while, apparently spark holds the objects used for the UI and this collection was growing constantly although we configured spark to run with  spark.ui.enabled: false. the solution was to limit it using the configuration parma spark.sql.ui.retainedExecutions. [spark sql ui data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu4P5.png)
We reproduced the memory issue easily since our dataset has around 300 columns so the UI saved data was very big.